# Scroll then snap to top not unsnapping

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

I'm trying to create snap to top divs that cover the entire page and I have it working, it's just that after they snap to the top they don't unsnap and stay fixed to the top.  I'm using the answer given by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) from this previous question [scroll then snap to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124389/scroll-then-snap-to-top) but I can't get it to unsnap.

Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xoluta/edit?html,css,output) of the code.

```js
    var h = 0;
    var notif;
    var notif2;
    var init;
    var docked = false;

    function getSize() {
      h = window.innerHeight;
      notif = document.getElementById("notif");
      notif2 = document.getElementById("notif2");
      var fl = document.getElementById("floater");
      init = notif.scrollTop;

      notif.style.top = "" + h + "px";

      var h2 = h / 2;
      fl.style.marginTop = "" + h2 + "px";
      notif.style.height = "" + h + "px";

      var twoh = 3 * h2;
      notif2.style.top = "" + h + "px";
      notif2.style.height = "" + h + "px";
    }

    window.onscroll = function() {

      if (!docked && (notif.offsetTop - document.body.scrollTop < 0)) {
        console.log("in loop");
        notif.style.top = 0;
        notif.style.position = 'fixed';
        notif2.style.marginTop = "" + h + "px";
        docked = true;
      } else if (docked && document.body.scrollTop <= init) {
        notif.style.position = 'block';
        while (notif.style.top <= h) {
          var ab = Math.abs(notif.offsetTop)
          var ab2 = Math.abs(document.body.scrollTop);
          notif.style.top = init + 'px';
        }
        if (notif.style.top == h || notif.style.top == h - 1) {
          docked = false;
        }
      }
    };
```

```html
<body onload="getSize()">
  <div class="contain">
    <div id="floater">
      <h1 class="white">Hello, World</h1>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>&ensp;<a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="announcements" id="notif">
    Please cover the previous text on the page. If this works i will be really excited.
  </div>

  <div class="announcements2" id="notif2">
    Cover the white page.
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the values used before you set these, and reset them when you "un-dock".  Simply setting "docked" to show that you're un-docked is not enough.
This code is an example of how to do that from your staring point.
Here's how I saved it and got something like the behaviour you mention

```
  var h = 0;  
  var notif;  
  var notif2;  
  var init;  
  var docked = false;  
  // holding space for reset values  
  var holdNotifyStyleTop;  
  var holdNotifyOffsetTop;  
  var holdNotif2StyleMarginTop;  

  function getSize() {
    h = window.innerHeight;
    notif = document.getElementById("notif");
    notif2 = document.getElementById("notif2");
    var fl = document.getElementById("floater");
    init = notif.offsetTop;

    notif.style.top = ""+h+"px";

    var h2 = h/2;
    fl.style.marginTop = ""+h2+"px";
    notif.style.height = ""+h+"px";

    var twoh = 3*h2;
    notif2.style.top=""+h+"px";
    notif2.style.height = ""+h+"px";
  }         

  window.onscroll = function () {

        if (!docked && (notif.offsetTop - document.body.scrollTop < 0))             {
            console.log("--- DOCKING ---");
            // save current values
            holdNotifyStyleTop = notif.style.top;
            holdNotifyOffsetTop = notif.offsetTop;
            holdNotif2StyleMarginTop = notif2.style.marginTop;
            notif.style.top = 0;
            notif.style.position = 'fixed'; 
            notif2.style.marginTop=""+h+"px";
            docked = true;

        } else if (docked && document.body.scrollTop <= init) { 
            console.log("--- Un-DOCKING ---");
            notif.style.top = holdNotifyStyleTop;
            notif.style.position = 'relative';
            notif2.style.marginTop=holdNotif2StyleMarginTop;
            notif.offsetTop = holdNotifyOffsetTop;
            docked = false; 
        }
    };
```

Comment: I do , that's what the `getSize()` function is for is to set the `notif.style.top = 0;` and when i try to undock it doesn't change it back to the way I had it before

Comment: If you check out the `jsbin` I have above you can see that it scrolls down after trying to undock

Comment: Here's how I saved it and got something like the behaviour you mention:

Comment: Okay that did the trick, it undocks from the top but the `div` that docks and undocks doesn't scroll off, it jumps off to the bottom of the page. Is there any way to scroll off away from the top?